# What is coin value for?

Tags: coin-crypt

There's a dollar value visible on my bag of coins.  It appears to be the sum total of the dollar values of each of the coins in my bag.

What is this value for?  Coins appear to have different dollar values as well (the [very rare](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/143279/what-can-i-do-with-very-rare-coins) yellow ones are worth $75), and I can't figure out what they are for either.  Is this information useful somehow, or does a higher dollar score benefit me somehow?

[image: $125 in the bag, as it were]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so after I got better at the game and was able to get a few floors down without dying, there appears to be shops set up periodically throughout the dungeon.

In the shop, you can spend your coins on useful items, or on bags of more coins.  This is where the monetary value of your coins comes into play.  You have to decide which coins you want to trade in exchange for the item you want to buy, and they have to add up to the item's price (or more).

There are a couple other instances where this becomes useful as well:

- There are some statues that 'look hungry' according to your character.  If you give them some coins, they will give you some different coins in return.  The higher the total value is of the coins you give them, the more coins you'll get in return.
- There are glowing pads you can give coins to in exchange for health.  The more value you give them, the more health you get in return.

---

It's important to note that when using the *Hermit* character, you will be unable to make use of any of these services, as all of your coins will be worthless.

[image: The Shop]

[image: Buying an item]